# Limit the displayed data on first page of Report then continue to next page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

Can anyone help me to achieve this.
I have a report that displays monthly attendance of employees.(The columns are EmployeeName, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday and TotalWorkHours which is the sum of hours from Monday to Sunday). What I want to do is to display only these columns in first page, then continue on the next page.
Currently my report displays wide page that depends on the given date range.Let me know if my explanation was unclear

Comment: Is it a matrix report? What does the dataset look like? Are you planning to display a week's worth of data on every page?

Comment: Yes every page should contain week's worth of data, at the end of sunday there should be an additional column(TotalOf Monday to sunday Column.. It is a matrix report BTW

Comment: You didn't answer all of my questions.

Comment: The dataset returns employeeName, WorkingHours, Date and DayName

Comment: Create a column in your dataset that returns a rank number by date, use that as your page group value for your matrix table.